# Flutter: Trying to display a widget conditionally based on whether a bool is true or false

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, typeerror

I want to display a widget based on whether a variable that is a bool is true or false. However I get the error: _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Widget').

```
import 'package:expense_tracker/Models/expense.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExpensesItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExpensesItem(this.isAdditionalDisplayed, this.expense, {super.key,});

  final Expense expense;
  final bool isAdditionalDisplayed; //HERE IS THE BOOL VARIABLE

  _displayAdditional() {
    if(isAdditionalDisplayed == true) {
      Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 100,
                width: 360,
                child: Text(expense.additional))],
                )
              ],
            );
    }
    if(isAdditionalDisplayed == false) {
      SizedBox(height: 0,);
    }
  } //HERE I ASK IF _DISPLAYADDITIONAL IS TRUE OR FALSE. IF ITS TRUE IT DISPLAYS THE WIDGET, IF IT'S FALSE IT DISPLAYS AN EMPTY SIZEDBOX.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 20,
          vertical: 16,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(expense.title),
            const SizedBox(height: 4),
            Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 360,
                      child: Text(expense.additional))],
                )
              ],
            ),
            _displayAdditional(), //HERE THE WIDGET SHOULD BE DISPLAYED. THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Tried adding to the 2nd if statement to check if _isAdditionalDisplayed is null. This gives the error that it can't be null and will always be false:
`if(isAdditionalDisplayed == false || isAdditionalDisplayed == null) {`
Error:
The operand can't be null, so the condition is always 'false'.
Try removing the condition, an enclosing condition, or the whole conditional statement.

Tried adding an exclimation mark when _displayAdditional is called:
`_displayAdditional()!,`
Error:
_TypeError (Null check operator used on a null value)

With both of those changes at once I get both errors. With one or the other I get one or the other errors.

This is very confusing. In one place it's saying isAdditionalDisplayed can't be null. In another it's saying it is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue is you are not returning the widgets from the function.

```
import 'package:expense_tracker/Models/expense.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExpensesItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExpensesItem(this.isAdditionalDisplayed, this.expense, {super.key,});

  final Expense expense;
  final bool isAdditionalDisplayed;

  Widget _displayAdditional() {
    return isAdditionalDisplayed ? Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 100,
                width: 360,
                child: Text(expense.additional))],
                )
              ],
            ) : SizedBox.shrink();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 20,
          vertical: 16,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(expense.title),
            const SizedBox(height: 4),
            Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 360,
                      child: Text(expense.additional))],
                )
              ],
            ),
            _displayAdditional(), 
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```